# How to add "Compare List" into cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, compare

I tried to add compare list into cms page, but it doesn't work

```
{{block type="catalog/product_compare" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Please whitlist block `catalog/product_compareand` check if its work

Answer (score 0):

Try the same using a phtml file means call the compare product template inside a phtml and after that call that phtml inside a cms page.
To add the compare product list inside a phtml use this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_compare")->setTemplate("catalog/product/compare/list.phtml")->toHtml();?
```

Comment: thanks for some advice, your code respond:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object`  I found some similar solution and It works:
`$clist = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_compare_list")->getItems(); ` + foreach